# R : everything that is not AND that is in one regular expression

Tags: r, regex

x is a string :

```
x="alt=\"white\"/>"
```

I want to extract `"white"` in one regex in R
I try

```
gsub(pattern ="[(^[:alpha:])|(alt)]" ,replacement ="" ,x =x)
```

But obviously, it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you [`regex`ing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348)?? bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
some_vector <- c("alt=\"white\"/>", "alt=\"black\"/>")
colours <- gsub('(alt)="([^"]+)"', '\\1=""', some_vector)
colours
# [1] "alt=\"\"/>" "alt=\"\"/>"
```

Generally, you should go for some parser instead.

Comment: ok thanks for ur answer. By parser, do you mean something like strsplit?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are interested in some pattern appearing within the quotes only:

```
gsub(".*\"(.*)\".*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "white"
```